# Cross Domain Request in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jersey

I have a Cross Domain JS request working with Firefox and Chrome but not with IE
I have found the following code (just the beggining for time saving)

```
jQuery.ajaxTransport('text html xml json', function(options, userOptions, jqXHR){....
```

That adds the transport for IE, and this works fine

The only problem I have now is that the XDomainRequest Object doesn't allow me to change the Content Type, it's being sent as plain/text and I need application/json

I'm using Java Jersey as the REST Container, is there a way that I can intercept all the calls in plain/text content-type and switch it to application/json ?

Or any other thoughs on how I might get this to work

Thanks in advance

Here is the Resource

```
@POST
@Path("/register")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public StatusResult register(UserRegistrationRequest urr) {
    //Calls the controller to register the producer, and returns result
    StatusResult result = UserController.register(urr);
    return result;
}
```

I tried adding another Consumes with MediaType.PLAIN_TEXT, but it doesn't work

I can see the Server being called, but some errors regarding the Enconding Type not Supported (or not being able to transform)

Comment: Does your resource class or method have `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`?

Comment: why does the mime of the json matter? (it should work as anything)